# Не работает админка в django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Разрабатывал сайт на django, всё работало отлично, затем перенёс на другой хостинг, и перестала работать админка. Ну, то есть, выдаёт страничку логина, но если ввести правильный, то `Incomplete response received from application`. С чем такое вообще может быть связано, никогда раньше не сталкивался?

PS на прошлом хосте был дефолтный `sqlite`, на новом подключил `mysql`, дампнул каждое приложение и перенёс на новый хост. Также бд на самом сайте работает, мне кажется, в чём-то другом проблема, но в чём - не знаю :(

Comment: Вот здесь - [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013637/django-admin-incomplete-response-received-from-application), который решили.

Comment: Ахахаха, оно само начало работать, притом, что я абсолютно ничего не исправлял ¯\_(ツ)_/¯